# MySQL returning other columns with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

Need a little bit of help with a query.

```
SELECT id,email FROM user_info WHERE username!='' 
     AND email='example@gmail.com' 
     GROUP BY email ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

What this does currently is fetch a distinct email but not the newest ID for an account under this email.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can apply an aggregate to the `id` field and it will return the most recent id for each email:

```
SELECT Max(id), email 
FROM user_info 
WHERE username!='' 
  AND email='example@gmail.com' 
GROUP BY email
```

Unfortunately, when you apply a `GROUP BY` without an aggregate there is no guarantee what `id` will be returned unless you specify to select the max.

If you want to return the username that is associated with the `max(id)`, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT i.MaxId, 
  i.email, 
  u.username
FROM user_info u
inner join
(
  select max(id) MaxId, email
  from user_info
  WHERE username!='' 
    AND email='example@gmail.com' 
  group by email
) i
  on u.id = i.maxid
  and u.email = i.email
WHERE username!='' 
  AND email='example@gmail.com';
```

Comment: That worked nicely. However I actually need to return a username with this as well. Found under the username column. Each new ID has a new username.

Comment: The `GROUP BY email` isn't useful/needed, since you're already have `email='example@gmail.com'`.

Comment: @David will you have multiple usernames for each email? Or just one?

Comment: There will be more than one row per email. But I only want the newest username and ID. Also in my example please ignore the email = '' as it's only there to run on myself to start with.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels I am still including the `GROUP BY` with the `WHERE` clause because most database products require columns in a `SELECT` list but not in an aggregate function to be included in a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score -1):

If by "newest id" you mean the largest value, then here's one approach that makes use of MySQL user variables to retain the value from previous rows, so a comparison can be made:

```
SELECT IF(u.email=@prev_email,1,0) AS dup_email_ind
     , u.id
     , u.username
     , @prev_email := u.email AS email
  FROM user_info u
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT @prev_email := NULL) i
 WHERE u.username != ''
   AND u.email = 'example@gmail.com'
 GROUP 
    BY u.email    DESC
     , u.id       DESC
     , u.username DESC
```

This returns all of the rows, with an indicator of whether the row is considered an older "duplicate" email or not. Rows that have `dup_email_ind = 1` are identified as older duplicates, `dup_email_ind` = 0 indicates that this row is the latest row (the row with the largest id value) for a given email value.

(Usually, when I'm looking for duplicates like this, it's helpful for me to return both, or all, of the rows that are "duplicates".)

To return only the rows with the "newest id", wrap the query above (as an inline view) in another query:  the output from the query is used a row source for the outer query.)

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM (
         -- the query above gets put here
       ) d
 WHERE d.dup_mail_ind = 0
```

---

Another approach is to use a correlated subqueries in the SELECT list, although this is really only suitable for returning small sets. (This approach can have serious performance issues with large sets.)

```
SELECT ( SELECT u1.id
           FROM user_info u1
          WHERE u1.email = e.email
            AND u1.username != ''
          ORDER BY u1.id DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS id
      , ( SELECT u2.username
           FROM user_info u2
          WHERE u2.email = e.email
            AND u2.username != ''
          ORDER BY u2.id DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS username
      , e.email
   FROM ( SELECT u.email
            FROM user_info u
           WHERE u.email = 'example@gmail.com'
             AND u.username != '' 
           GROUP BY u.email
        ) e
```

Comment: I think using a cross join for this task is overkill, and that second example isn't useful.

Comment: @Octopi: Thanks for the comments. I don't understand what you mean by "overkill". The purpose of the inline view is to initialize a user variable. Omitting the inline view and performing the initialization in a separate statement has no impact on performance. The CROSS keyword is optional, it's ignored by MySQL and has no impact on the generated plan.  The second statement demonstrates another technique, using a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. And I have found that this technique can be useful to the point of being indispensable in some cases.